# 10gbase-kr autonegociation and ICs

Tags: fpga, ethernet, processor

My goal is to propose building a 3U VPX card which connects to a backplane. After some research, the preferred connection between cards is over 10gbase-kr (although SGMII is supported in some applications, I'd like to avoid it to make the card more standardized). I have a couple of questions:

1. What is auto-negotiation for? Can it go down to 1gbase-kr? From what I've read, 1gbase-kr does not exist, so if it can't lower the speed, what is it used for?
2. What's the best IC to interface with this? I've seen that FPGAs are preferred, but I'd like to avoid one if possible. A processor to me is far more attractive.

Thank you.

Comment: "What's the best IC" is an opinion-based shopping question - and therefore off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

10Gbase-kr supports auto-negotiation, but it is optional.

See [this tutorial](https://www.ieee802.org/802_tutorials/06-July/10GBASE-KR_FEC_Tutorial_1407.pdf).

TI have a great [application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla351a/slla351a.pdf?ts=1638144412178&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) (SLLA351A–February 2019) that covers most of the information you may need on implementation.

### What Happens When Link Training is Activated?

Through sending test sequences transmitter and receiver try to find the best configuration of the precursor and post-cursor 1 parameters, which are explained in Section 4, for optimal channel matching.

For each test, setting the BER will be determined and saved internally in the device. Measurement data is accessible after link training has successfully completed. Link training for 10 GBASE-KR is enabled by default, when the device is powered up. To enable it manually, for example after a bring-up procedure, bit 1 in the PMA layer (device address 0x01) in register LT_TRAIN_CONTROL (register address 0x96, default 0x0002) has to be set high. For link training to then become active, a data path reset is necessary, which is done by setting bit 3 under device address 0x1E in register 0x000E.

The actual link training BER results can be read from the PMA layer’s register 0x9012 for the TLK10034 and 0x9022 for the TLK10232. Setting bit 12 under device address 0x01 in register 0x9001 initiates the read out starting with the minimum post-cursor de-emphasis level.